# Stepped table lookup in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I use this code from the book that illustartes exampel of stepped table looup:

```
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.VisuaLBasic

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim rangeLimit() as Double = {50.0, 65.0, 75.0, 90.0, 100.0}
        Dim grade() as String = {"F", "D", "C", "B", "A"}
        Dim maxGradeLevel = grade.length - 1

        Dim gradeLevel = 0
        Dim studentGrade = "A"
        Dim studentScore = 50

        While((studentGrade = "A") and (gradeLevel < maxGradeLevel))
            if(studentScore < rangeLimit(gradeLevel)) then
                studentGrade = grade(gradeLevel)
            End if
            gradeLevel = gradeLevel + 100
        End While
        Print(studentGrade)
    End Sub
End Module
```

[Code is here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dzeo5W)

I wonder how does it work and how to fix this error after compiling:

```
Run-time exception (line -1): Conversion from string "A" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

Comment: it is visual basic

Comment: Which Visual Basic? It has come in many forms over the years: VBA, VBScript, VB6 (and earlier), VB.Net, etc, and each one of those has it's own distinct quirks. Based on the error message, this looks like .Net, but even there the context can matter: web vs console vs wpf vs winforms, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `Console.WriteLine()` instead of `Print()`.

Also:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim studentScore As Double = 50.0
        Console.WriteLine(GetGrade(studentScore))
    End Sub
    
    Public Function GetGrade(score As Double) As String
        Dim gradeTable = { 
            (50.0,  "F"), 
            (65.0,  "D"), 
            (75.0,  "C"), 
            (90.0,  "B"), 
            (100.0, "A") 
        }
        Return gradeTable.First(Function(g) g.Item1 >= Score).Item2
    End Function
End Module
```

See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/CKTNCE

Personally, though, I prefer to use the minimum grade instead of the maximum for the boundaries. I find it far more likely you'll have extra credit push a score above 100 than you'll have something send you a negative score, and using maximum grades causes problems in that situation:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim studentScore As Double = 50.0
        Console.WriteLine(GetGrade(studentScore))
    End Sub
    
    Public Function GetGrade(score As Double) As String
        Dim gradeTable = { 
            (90.0, "A"), 
            (75.0, "B"), 
            (65.0, "C"), 
            (50.0, "D"), 
            ( 0.0, "F") 
        }
        Return gradeTable.First(Function(g) g.Item1 >= Score).Item2
    End Function
End Module
```

You also need to be careful with your equality comparisons. `>=` and `>` mean different things, and only one is correct.

Comment: Could you comment what logic this code makes?

Comment: It uses an array of Tuples, instead of trying to match up two arrays by index (matching arrays by index is _almost never_ a good idea). You can lookup IEnumerable.First() in the .Net documentation, but basically it loops through the item (`gradeTable` in this case) and returns the first item that matches the anonymous predicate function.